# How to add a block of text to a Word document and monitor changes to it?

Tags: office-js

I would like to create a Word Add-in which can add a block of text to a document. This block should have markers at its beginning and end so that I can check whether the user made changes to this block of text.

As an example, think of an Add-in which allows the user to add some boilerplate – one or more paragraphs – to her document. If the user changes this boilerplate, I would like to inform the user of the consequences of her changes.

I am somewhat aware of custom document properties, but they seem to be designed for smaller amounts of texts like names. Given [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.documentproperties?view=office-js#customproperties) it also seems to be read only from the Javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

The Bindings system and the BindingChangedEvent were invented for just this scenario. For some details see [Detect changes to data ... in a binding](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/bind-to-regions-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet.md#detect-changes-to-data-or-the-selection-in-a-binding).